# Expandable ListView Adapter getChildrenCount NPE

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I need to implement expandable ListView, but I have null pointer exception in adapter at `getChildrenCount()` line of the code.

Here is the code of **adapter**:

```
public class DigitalMenuListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private ArrayList<ProductCategory> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
// private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Products>> _listDataChild;
private ProductCategory productCategory;
private Products products;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Products>> productsList;

public DigitalMenuListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductCategory> productCategoryList,
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Products>> listDataForChild) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = productCategoryList;
    this.productsList = listDataForChild;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
     return null;

}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    products = productsList.get(childPosition).get(childPosition);
    final String childText = products.getName();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.digital_menu_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

      return this.productsList.get(groupPosition).size();    }

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    productCategory = _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    String headerTitle = productCategory.getName();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.digital_menu_list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is the code of **main activity**, where I get data from server, parse JSON and then set data to modes, listview, hashmap and adapter.

ProductsCategory is the model for parent expandable ListView data, Products is the model for child ListView data.

```
public class LocationMenuFragment extends Fragment {

private String locationId;
// Shared Preferences
private PreferencesManager mPrefs;

// Hash
private String hash;
private HttpEntity resEntity;
private String response_str, accesToken, id;

//UI
private ExpandableListView elvDigitalMenu;
private DigitalMenuListAdapter listAdapter;

//Models and Lists
private ProductCategory productCategory;
private ArrayList<ProductCategory> productCategoryList = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();
private Products products;
private ArrayList<Products> productsList;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Products>> listDataForChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Products>>();



public LocationMenuFragment init(String id) {

    LocationMenuFragment fragment = new LocationMenuFragment();
    // Supply val input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    locationId = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("id")
            : "";
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_menu,
            container, false);

    getData();

    //UI
    elvDigitalMenu = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.elv_digital_menu);



    new SendDataToServer().execute(locationId);

    //init adapter

    //set adapter
    //elvDigitalMenu.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    return rootView;
}


// Get Location ID from LocationListActivity class and get accesToken
private void getData() {
    mPrefs = new PreferencesManager(getActivity());
    accesToken = mPrefs.getAccesToken();
}

private void getDigitalMenu(String id) {

    getHash();

    Log.d("Hash", hash);

    String urlString = URLManager.DIGITAL_MENU + accesToken + "&hash="
            + hash;

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);

        StringBody sbId = new StringBody(id);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("id", sbId);          

        post.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE", response_str);
                Log.d("TAG", "Response from server : n "+ response_str);                            

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}


private class SendDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        getDigitalMenu(params[0].toString());

        if(response_str != null){
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response_str);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
                    String description = jsonObj.getString("description");
                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                    productCategory = new ProductCategory(name, description);
                    productCategoryList.add(productCategory);
                    JSONArray productsArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");
                    productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();

                    for(int j=0;j<productsArray.length();j++){
                        JSONObject  productsObject = productsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String id = productsObject.getString("ID");
                        Log.d("TAG", id);

                        String productName = productsObject.getString("name");
                        String productDescription = productsObject.getString("description");
                        String imagesCount = productsObject.getString("imagesCount");
                        String recommendsCount = productsObject.getString("recommendsCount");
                        String userRecommended = productsObject.getString("userRecommended");
                        //fali images i recommends niz

                        products = new Products(id, productName, productDescription, imagesCount, recommendsCount, userRecommended);
                        productsList.add(products);
                        listDataForChild.put(name, productsList);
                        //productsList.clear();


                    }




                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("TAG", "response null");

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        /*for(int i=0;i<productCategoryList.size();i++){
                listDataForChild.put(productCategoryList.get(i).toString(), productsList);
        }*/
        ArrayList<Products> value;
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Products>> entry : listDataForChild.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", "KEY: "+key);
           value  = entry.getValue();
            for(int k=0;k<value.size();k++){
                products = value.get(k);
                Log.d("TAG", products.getName());
            }
        }
        listAdapter = new DigitalMenuListAdapter(getActivity(), productCategoryList, listDataForChild);

        elvDigitalMenu.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

private void getHash() {

    String finalStringForHash = URLManager.DIGITAL_MENU;

    HashSHA256 h = new HashSHA256();
    try {
        hash = HashSHA256.hashMac(finalStringForHash);
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: IDK if you should initialize the adapter `onPostExecute`. Since it runs asynchronous, it might give you a false impression that the object being set, and maybe that will cause the NPE. How is `productCategoryList` inside your `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: I know that is not good practice to initialize the adapter onPostExecute, but I = did not understand your question about productCategoryList?

Comment: in your `onPostExecute` when you are initializing the adapter, the `productCategoryList` is null or what?

Comment: It's not nul, just debugged it. Here is the image: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/7/Wb/17drWyGO/not-null.png

Comment: what about the `listDataForChild`. is it null? also check how the respective variables are being received inside the adapter. are they null there?

Comment: Nope, listDataForChild is not null. In adapter it seems that data is received, here is the image: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2D/13M/1GdjwgCB/adapter.png

Comment: Here is NPE: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/C/JH/MueBn3C/npe.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52124/discussion-between-rogcg-and-zookey)